# Query with exclusive OR join condition with ActiveRecord and Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

I have two tables.

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "slug"
  t.boolean  "is_public",  default: false
  t.integer  "row_order"
end

create_table "localizations", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "lang"
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "content"
  t.integer  "category_id"
end
```

I need to perform a query that would return some distinct categories attributes along with corresponding `localizations.title` for each of them. The condition is that joined localizations are in one of two passed `lang` values, first of which has precedence.

My first attempt was:

```
Category.
  select(:id, :slug, :row_order).
  select('localizations.title AS localized_title').
  distinct.
  joins(:localizations).
  where(localizations.lang = :first OR localizations.lang = :last, first: 'en', last: 'pl')
```

However it did not work fully as expected, because if there was a translation with `lang = 'en'` and another with `lang = 'pl'` both of them were returned as they were treated as distinct records. As far as I know there is no `XOR` operator in `postgres`.

My second attempt was to create a condition inside a where clause which would query for localization with `lang = 'en'` first, and if such localization doesn't exist - `lang = 'pl'`:

```
Category.
  select(:id, :slug, :row_order).
  select('localizations.title AS localized_title').
  distinct.
  joins(:localizations).
  where('localizations.lang = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT localizations.id FROM localizations WHERE localizations.lang = :first) THEN :first ELSE :last', first: 'en', last: 'pl')
```

Unfortunately, it throws syntax error for some reason.

Comment: The `CASE` is missing an `END` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, you were right :) Also, I had to include the join condition in subquery to make it work properly - `SELECT localizations.id FROM localizations WHERE localizations.lang = :first AND localizations.category_id = categories.id`